# Remove XCode alerts of intended missing @1x images

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, image

I'm making a ObjC/Swift application, and the client stipulated that devices that use @1x images will no longer be supported, so these images should be deleted from the project to make it lighter.
I have done this, but I receive several alerts on the Xcode project:

> The file "image_name@1x.png" for the image set "image_name@1x" does not exists.

Bearing in mind that these are intended missing files, there is any way to make these alerts disappear?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to avoid the warning if you provide raster images but don't include @1x scale.

These days it's pretty common to include a single, universal graphic in a vector form like pdf. The system then generates whatever scale is needed for each target device.

Unless you're using larger raster graphics I suggest you use that approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I think this could be a good approach, but I'll not be able to request this to the client.

Comment: Apple should just get rid of @1x. Are there any non-retina devices that support the latest OS? I think the iPhone 4 (not the 4S) was the last non-retina iPhone, and the original iPad mini was the last non-retina iPad. Those are both quite old now. (It looks like they discontinued the iPad mini in 2015, which is about a thousand years ago in mobile years.)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you now have only a single image left? If so, you could change the *Scales* setting in the asset inspector to *Single Scale* as shown in the image below and hopefully that will fix your problem.

[image: setting single scale in inspector]

Comment: Thanks for answering!
No, I still got the @ x2 and @ x3 images.

Comment: Here's a suggestion - create a small e.g. 1x1 red pixel or small client logo image and put that in all the 1x spots. That way you can easily see if one gets use accidentally, you reduce the size of the app and you get rid of the warnings and (hopefully) the client is happy.